# How to get Glide to work with Android Studio 3.0?

Tags: java, android, android-glide, android-studio-3.0

Since upgrading to Android Studio 3.0, I've had trouble getting 'AppGlideModule' to be recognized. Android Studio doesn't recognize the import

```
import com.bumptech.glide.module.AppGlideModule;
```

[see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XTGVL.png)

I have tried updating **'compile'** to **'implementation'**. I have also tried cleaning and rebuilding the projects, as well as invalidating caches/restarting.

**build.gradle (module:app)**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.test"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 26
        buildToolsVersion "26.0.2"
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'

    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.9.0'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:annotations:4.2.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.2.0'
}
```

I feel like **'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.2.0'** isn't being recognized and that's why **'GlideAppModule'** is throwing an error but I can't figure out why.

**EDIT:** 'com.github.bumptech.glide:comiler:4.2.0' is the cause of the error. This was working before updating to Android Studio 3.0

**stacktrace**

```
Executing tasks: [clean, :app:assembleDebug]

Configuration on demand is an incubating feature.
:clean
:app:clean
:app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugBuild
:app:compileDebugAidl
:app:compileDebugRenderscript
:app:checkDebugManifest
:app:generateDebugBuildConfig
:app:prepareLintJar UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResValues
:app:generateDebugResources
:app:mergeDebugResources
:app:createDebugCompatibleScreenManifests
:app:processDebugManifest
:app:splitsDiscoveryTaskDebug
:app:processDebugResources
:app:generateDebugSources
:app:javaPreCompileDebug
:app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac
C:\Users\user\Documents\test\app\src\main\java\com\example\test\MyAppGlideModule.java:4: error: package com.bumptech.glide.module does not exist
import com.bumptech.glide.module.AppGlideModule;
                                ^
C:\Users\user\Documents\test\app\src\main\java\com\example\test\MyAppGlideModule.java:7: error: cannot find symbol
public final class MyAppGlideModule extends AppGlideModule {}
                                            ^
  symbol: class AppGlideModule

 FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> java.lang.NullPointerException: element == null

* Try:
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:100)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:70)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:63)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.java:54)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:58)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:88)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:54)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:34)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker$1.run(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:248)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:197)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:107)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:241)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:230)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:124)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.access$200(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:80)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:105)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:99)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:625)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.executeWithTask(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:580)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:99)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NullPointerException: element == null
    at com.sun.tools.javac.main.Main.compile(Main.java:553)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTaskImpl.doCall(JavacTaskImpl.java:129)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTaskImpl.call(JavacTaskImpl.java:138)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.JdkJavaCompiler.execute(JdkJavaCompiler.java:49)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.JdkJavaCompiler.execute(JdkJavaCompiler.java:36)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.NormalizingJavaCompiler.delegateAndHandleErrors(NormalizingJavaCompiler.java:99)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.NormalizingJavaCompiler.execute(NormalizingJavaCompiler.java:52)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.NormalizingJavaCompiler.execute(NormalizingJavaCompiler.java:37)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.CleaningJavaCompilerSupport.execute(CleaningJavaCompilerSupport.java:35)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.CleaningJavaCompilerSupport.execute(CleaningJavaCompilerSupport.java:25)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.incremental.IncrementalCompilationFinalizer.execute(IncrementalCompilationFinalizer.java:39)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.incremental.IncrementalCompilationFinalizer.execute(IncrementalCompilationFinalizer.java:24)
    at org.gradle.api.tasks.compile.JavaCompile.performCompilation(JavaCompile.java:198)
    at org.gradle.api.tasks.compile.JavaCompile.compile(JavaCompile.java:129)
    at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.factory.AndroidJavaCompile.compile(AndroidJavaCompile.java:95)
    at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$IncrementalTaskAction.doExecute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:173)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$StandardTaskAction.execute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:134)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$StandardTaskAction.execute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:121)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$1.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:122)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:197)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:107)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:111)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:92)
    ... 27 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: element == null
    at com.bumptech.glide.repackaged.com.squareup.javapoet.Util.checkNotNull(Util.java:68)
    at com.bumptech.glide.repackaged.com.squareup.javapoet.ClassName.get(ClassName.java:209)
    at com.bumptech.glide.annotation.compiler.RequestManagerGenerator.<init>(RequestManagerGenerator.java:83)
    at com.bumptech.glide.annotation.compiler.AppModuleProcessor.<init>(AppModuleProcessor.java:42)
    at com.bumptech.glide.annotation.compiler.GlideAnnotationProcessor.init(GlideAnnotationProcessor.java:81)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment$ProcessorState.<init>(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:500)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment$DiscoveredProcessors$ProcessorStateIterator.next(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:597)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.discoverAndRunProcs(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:690)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.access$1800(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:91)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment$Round.run(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:1035)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.doProcessing(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:1176)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.processAnnotations(JavaCompiler.java:1170)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.compile(JavaCompiler.java:856)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.main.Main.compile(Main.java:523)
    ... 52 more


* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 8s

16 actionable tasks: 15 executed, 1 up-to-date
```

Comment: with these two entries, my is working fine . `compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.0.0-RC0'
 annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.0.0-RC0'`. Your definitley looks different though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Changing

```
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:annotations:4.2.0'
annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.2.0'
```

to

```
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.2.0'
annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.2.0'
```

has solved my issue. I don't know how I ended up with a different implementation but there it is.

Comment: I had this same issue. i deleted glide implementation and forgot to delete the annotationProcessor. This answer solves it for me

Answer (score 0):

This is not supported in Kotlin:

```
annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.2.0'
```

You need to use Kapt instead of annotationProcessor

```
kapt 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.2.0'
```

And then

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
```

Full code example:

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    // for facebook sdk conflict
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:26.1.0'

    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:11.4.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.4.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.4.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.4.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:11.4.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-config:11.4.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.4.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:11.4.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-appindexing:11.4.2'

    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.4.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.4.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.4.2'


    implementation 'com.firebase:geofire-android:2.1.2'
    implementation 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.5+'
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'
    implementation 'com.afollestad.material-dialogs:core:0.9.5.0'
    implementation 'com.kila.apprater_dialog.lars:apprater-dialog:1.2.0'

    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.2.0'
    kapt 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.2.0'

    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:0.19.3'

    androidTestImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'

    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:$kotlin_version"
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
```

Comment: This is a Java project though, I'm not using kotlin.

Comment: Oh, my mistake. Hope this info will be useful to others when web searching, though.